# snoop: cannot open "vnet0": Permission denied

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, solaris-11, snoop

Getting the error when tried to take a capture on a solaris machine.

I have tried to run the snoop command

```
$ /usr/sbin/snoop -o file.pcap
snoop: cannot open "vnet0": Permission denied

$ uname -a
SunOS sdp-2 5.10 Generic_150400-12 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe snoop requires root privileges to do packet capture?

Comment: Are you running the command as root or with another user?

Comment: I was running the command other than root user.But in that case I think it must work

Comment: ppriv -eD snoop -o /var/tmp/file.pcap -d vnet0

This should tell you what privs you're missing as that user, you can then assign rights to the user via RBAC.